# Is there a better way to execute dynamic SQL that doesn't use a cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, cursor, execute, dynamic-sql

I have dynamic SQL stored in a SQL table that I have to execute under certain conditions. Currently, we use cursors to handle that for us, but I was always told to avoid cursors when possible as they aren't the most efficient way of doing things. So, my question is: how do I execute dynamic SQL without them (if there's a way)? The entire system is built around this dynamic SQL mess, so there is no changing it.

For this, just assume the table has `Id AS IDENTITY` and `SQL AS VARCHAR` fields, where the SQL field contains the SQL to be executed (obviously).

**EDIT:** 
Basically, I want to loop through the table and execute the SQL in the SQL column.

So, a row in the table will basically look like this:

```
ID   SQL
--   ----------------------
1    SELECT * FROM RECORD
2    SELECT * FROM PERSON
3    SELECT * FROM LOCATION
```

I haven't written any code because what I'd write is a cursor to traverse through the table and execute it. I just don't know of any other ways of looping a table and executing that string as a SQL query other than something like:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE _cursor CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT  [SQL]
    FROM    #tmp2

OPEN _cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM _cursor INTO @sql

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        PRINT ( @sql )
    END
CLOSE _cursor   
DEALLOCATE _cursor
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL and cursors are orthogonal concepts - one has no bearing on the other. Yes, they may come together in your codebase, but there is no inherent connection. Post some code so we can understand the link.

Comment: Seeing your code would help.  Dynamic SQL and cursors have nothing to do with each other, unless you're actually using dynamic SQL in a cursor.

Comment: I'm aware they don't have anything to do with one another, I just don't know another way to loop through a table, *without using them*, and execute dynamic SQL.

Comment: This looks like a rather broken design. Why have SQL _in_ your tables???

Comment: @Oded Can't be changed. Since you haven't posted an answer, may I assume there is NO better way to traverse and execute or you don't know of one offhand?

Comment: Not really - with such a broken design, unless you are OK with extracting to application code to build up a large SQL string to execute, this is the next "best".

Comment: @Oded so you're saying you don't envy my task of dealing with this on a daily basis? =)

Comment: I recently dealt with worse. Way worse (XML in the DB, containing details of what stored procedure to call + required parameters), but I do sympathise.

Comment: @Oded I swear I'm not trying to one-up you here, but we have that too. We have a parameters table that links to stored procedures, all of which is called dynamically as described above. Luckily, it's a great place to work, but there have been "missteps" in design.

Comment: Aye, creative designs where no one thought that there might be a better way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any number of concatenation tricks to make one big batch without using a cursor, I personally use the `FOR XML` trick a lot.

Here's an overview:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

However, the cursor (while generally a code smell) isn't going to contribute a terrible amount to the non-performance of this.  And you will have an opportunity to handle errors etc a lot easier than with a single batch.

In addition, if you have DDL in some of those statements which has to be the first statement in a batch, then you would need to submit them in separate batches. EXEC or sp_executesql doesn't implement any batch splitting like SSMS has the GO batch separator.

Comment: I don't want to think about DDL in a table via sp_executesql. Please expunge that! :)

Comment: @podiluska This structure is equivalent to job steps you might have in the Agent.  So it's perfectly reasonable to think that people might create a table, populate it from an import, process it and then drop the table.  There's nothing generally wrong with the construct, if used appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fundamental flaws in this whole schema....

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
   select @sql = '' 
   select @sql = @sql + SQL + ';' from #tmp2  

   exec sp_executesql @sql
```

At least we've got rid of your cursor now :)

EDIT: Code that is working for me...

```
create table #tmp2 (sql nvarchar(100))
insert #tmp2 values ('select * from sysobjects')
insert #tmp2 values  ('Select * from sysColumns')    
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
   select @sql = '' 
   select @sql = @sql + SQL + ';' from #tmp2       
   exec sp_executesql @sql        
drop table #tmp2
```

Comment: Trust me dude, it's a nightmare to work with. The entire application is dependent on this structure, so it's not something we can just rip out and replace. We'd have to take it back to design and re-code nearly everything and that's not an option.

Comment: That's life, isn't it. How's the job market where you are? :)

Comment: Flourishing...I see what you did there. =)

Comment: This didn't work for me. Shows (3 row(s) affected), but I get no results with exec or print.

Comment: Yes. I even fired up a SQL 2005 instance to check. Are you in the right database or are there some permission issues?

Comment: All is good on my end. I have several queries in the same open window - one to fill the temp table, displaying #tmp2's contents and then your code. I see rows have been "affected", so something is happening, I'm just not getting the results in the window, nor am I seeing the print in the Messages window.

Comment: I've put my test code into the main answer. I swear it's working :)